# MDX Query Taking very long time when executed from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have a query that takes very long time when queries from an SSRS Report (25 Minutes).

When I try to execute it from SSMS, I get the following error after 1 minute:

> Executing the query ...
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

```sql
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[Invoice Qty MT - VW Fact Total Sales],
    [Measures].[Invoice Value EGPUSD - VW Fact Total Sales]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {
    (
[Dim Invoice Date].[Year].[Year].allmembers *
[Dim Company].[Data Area ID].[Data Area ID].allmembers *
[Dim Customer].[Customer Type].[Customer Type].allmembers *
[Dim Invoice Date].[Month Str].[Month Str].allmembers *
[Dim Invoice Date].[Month Eng].[Month Eng].allmembers *
  [Dim Customer].[Customer Classification].[Customer Classification].allmembers
      *
  [Dim Item].[Item Number].[Item Number].allmembers *
      [Dim Item].[Item Name].[Item Name].allmembers *
  [Dim Customer].[Customer Num].[Customer Num].allmembers *
  [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name].allmembers *
  [Dim Item].[Factory Packing Group EN].[Factory Packing Group EN].allmembers *
[Dim Item].[Factory Packaging Group ID].[Factory Packaging Group ID].allmembers
)
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, member_unique_name ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT
     (
       {
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[1],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[2],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[3],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[4],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[5],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[6],
         [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[7]
       }
     ) ON COLUMNS
   FROM [BI_Cube])
WHERE (
      [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].currentmember
    ) CELL PROPERTIES value, back_color, fore_color, formatted_value,
format_string, font_name, font_size, font_flags
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `System.OutOfMemory` error is a client-side error in SSMS which means the query returned more data than fit in memory. Try closing and reopening SSMS. Also the following query changes will help (specifically reducing the cell properties that are returned to just VALUE).

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Invoice Qty MT - VW Fact Total Sales], [Measures].[Invoice Value EGPUSD - VW Fact Total Sales] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { (
  [Dim Invoice Date].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim Invoice Date].[Month Str].[Month Str].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Invoice Date].[Month Eng].[Month Eng].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Company].[Data Area ID].[Data Area ID].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim Customer].[Customer Type].[Customer Type].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Customer].[Customer Classification].[Customer Classification].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Customer].[Customer Num].[Customer Num].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim Item].[Item Number].[Item Number].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Item].[Item Name].[Item Name].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim Item].[Factory Packing Group EN].[Factory Packing Group EN].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim Item].[Factory Packaging Group ID].[Factory Packaging Group ID].ALLMEMBERS 
) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[1], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[2], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[3], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[4], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[5], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[6], [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].&[7] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [BI_Cube]) WHERE ( [Dim Packing Group].[Packing Group ID].CurrentMember ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Putting all attributes from a single dimension together should help performance. Also I trimmed down the CELL PROPERTIES and DIMENSION PROPERTIES to just the ones you likely use in the SSRS report.

Answer (score -1):

The error is self-explanatory. You don't have memory to calculate the huge crossjoin you got there.

Try to remove some of them, filter your data a bit more or use Properties instead of including everything in crossjoins.

[User-Defined Member Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-member-properties-user-defined-member-properties)

Comment: The suggestion to use member properties is a good one though!

Comment: This error message is a client-side error not server side. You can tell because it’s a .NET error.